# prove by induction that (2n)!≥2^n(n!)^2

Tags: analysis, induction, factorial

I know that the following maths and factorials properties are useful in my problem but I don't really know how to actually get them into it a rigorous way:

$2\times 2^n=2^{n+1}$ 
$((n+1)!)/(n!)=n+1 $

So I did

$2((2n)!)≥2\times 2^n(n!)^2$

$2((2n)!)≥2^(n+1)(n!)^2$

But then I don't really know what to do for the $2((2n)!)$ and the $(n!)^2$; how to get them to have n+1

Comment: Please consider using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting.

Comment: You should have $2(2n+1)! ≥ 2^{n+1} \left((n+1)! \right)^2$ instead.